# TypeScript Generic to change all types of a particular type to another

Tags: typescript, generics, ternary

I'm trying to come up with a typescript type that takes an object and sets all keys of type `number` to be `string`.  The following doesn't work:

```js
export type ChangeTypeOfKeys<T extends object> = {
  [key in keyof T]: key extends number ? string : T[key]
}

const c: ChangeTypeOfKeys<{ a: number, b: boolean }> = {
    a: 'ok',
    b: false,
}
```

The resulting type should be `{ a: string, b: boolean }`, but instead I get a TS error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
input.tsx(5, 29): The expected type comes from property 'a' which is declared here on type 'ChangeTypeOfKeys<{ a: number; b: boolean; }>'
```

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCALAhgOwObAAqywA8gGYDSwiAzgDyFygzA4AmtcEARgFbAAxjAB8cALxwA3gCg4cANoBrGnACWOOCsQRycQgF0AXFtUs2nODgCuAWx7AocAPxxaMKBrxwThZTQMZAF8ZGUEIHHc4QRNMXAJiFApqOnopOCwTG3tHABo4HhMeCAgAG2BcOCCxSVl5eUy4AHIIJSbcuXrCuHIsUtpgDpCgA)

I think the issue is related to how I'm using `key` in `key in keyof T`, since replacing `key extends number` with another argument works:

```js
export type ChangeTypeOfKeys<T extends object, Replace> = {
  [key in keyof T]: Replace extends number ? string : T[key]
}

const c: ChangeTypeOfKeys<{ a: number, b: boolean }, number> = {
    a: 'ok',
    b: 'ok',
}
```

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCALAhgOwObAAqywA8gGYDSwiAzgDyFygzA4AmtcEARgFbAAxjAA0cAErAwAGyyDgAPjgBeOAG8AUHDgBtANY04ASxxwDiCOTiEAugC4JU2fOYhWHLjgCuAWx7AoOAB+OFoYKBM8OAdCfRobDQBfDQ1BCBwwuEEHTFwCYhQKajp6NTgsB28-ALEeBx4ICGlgXDhEsSr-KCVVTW1tCrgAcgg9IZEtfrrh0fGkjSA)

Not sure if there are any special properties with `key` that I'm missing here.  TIA!

Comment: Sorry, do you want to change the property's key type or the property's value type?

Comment: It was the property's value type, but you figured it out :) Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value of property referenced by `key`, do this:

```
export type ChangeTypeOfKeys<T extends object> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends number ? string : T[key]
  //                ^^^^^^
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCALAhgOwObAAqywA8gGYDSwiAzgDyFygzA4AmtcEARgFbAAxjAB8cALxwA3gCg4cANoBrGnACWOOCsQRycQgF0AXPuU0DzEKw5ccAVwC2PYFDgB%20OLRhQNeOCcIzRAMZAF8ZGUEIHC84QRNMXAJiFApqOnopOCwTeycXABo4HhMeCAgAG2BcOFCxSVl5eRy4AHIIJVaCuSaSuHIsCtpgbvCgA)

---

The type of `key` will always be `string` in the example you gave. To be absolutely clear, in your code:

- `key` refers to the name of a property,
- `T[key]` refers to the property named `key` on type `T`.

<sub>*Also note, `extends object` allows for `[]` types (among others), which might not be what you want. Try extending from `{}` or `Record<string, any>` instead.*</sub>